# Leaderboard, rank query, how to return the rows above/below a users rank

Tags: c#, php, sql, unity-game-engine

Given this query, if I want to pull the rank of a specific individual where I know there $name and $score and return the rows above/below that rank (say +/- 4), how would I go about doing that?

```
$query = "SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank,
            uniqueID,
            name,
            score
        FROM scores, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
        ORDER by score DESC";
```

I'm coding in php, using MySQL and C# in Unity. My game is making a call to the server and running the php code. Goal is to echo the information and parse the information back in the game.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is this query in a stored proc? Why are you assigning values to variables in a SQL SELECT?

Comment: @Programmer: I'm stuck on creating a query to pull the rank of the user after assigning everybody in the db a rank. And then pulling the rows above/below that rank.

Comment: @SloanThrasher: I'm assigning a variable curRank because I want to use curRank to return the users above/below the rank of the user who just played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of your `:=`, I'm assuming you are using PostgreSQL, correct?  I'm more familiar with the T-SQL syntax; but regardless, both PostgreSQL and T-SQL have windowing functions.  You could implement something similar to the following (I left out variables for you to fill-in):

```
$query = "WITH scoreOrder
    AS
    (
        SELECT uniqueID,
            name,
            score,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC, uniqueID DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM scores
        ORDER BY uniqueID DESC
    )
    SELECT ns.*
    FROM scoreOrder ms --Your matching score
    INNER JOIN scoreOrder ns --Your nearby scores
    ON ms.name = /* your name variable */
        AND ms.score = /* your score variable */
        AND ns.RowNum BETWEEN ms.RowNum - /* your offset */ and ms.RowNum + /* your offset */";
```

Explanation: First, we're creating a common table expression called `scoreOrder`, and projecting a `RowNum` column for your scores.  In short, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC, uniqueID DESC)` is just saying, "I am returning the row number of this record *ordered by* `score` and `uniqueID`, both descending and in that order."  Then, you join that CTE with itself... `ms` will be your score that you match with, and you join *that* with `ns` where the `ns.RowNum` will be between your `ms.RowNum`, plus or minus your offset.

There are a ton of other windowing functions. ***Here are some others that could be more or less appropriate for your scenario:***

- `ROW_NUMBER()` - the rownumber of the record
- `RANK()` - the rank of the    record, duplicating in ties and includes
  gaps (i.e., if 2nd place    ties, you would have *1st, 2nd, 2nd,
  4th*)
- `DENSE_RANK()` - same as    rank, except that it fills in the gaps
  (i.e., if 2nd place ties, you    would have *1st, 2nd, 2nd, 3rd*)

For more info, check the PostgreSQL documentation on [windowing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) and their [tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html)

### Update:

Unfornately, MySQL does not support windowing functions or common table expressions.  In your scenario, you will have to put the results of your previous query into a temp table, then doing a similar join as demonstrated above.  So for example...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS allRankings AS 
(
  SELECT @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS Rank,
        uniqueID,
        name,
        score
    FROM scores, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER by score DESC, uniqueID
);

SELECT r.*
FROM allRankings r 
INNER JOIN allRankings myRank
ON r.Rank BETWEEN myRank.Rank - <your offset>  AND myRank.Rank + <your offset>
    AND myRank.name = <your name> 
    AND myRank.score = <your score> 
ORDER by r.Rank;
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle link for an example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04cfb9/3) (I'm not using a temp table on SQLFiddle because you have to build tables in the Build Schema window).

Comment: You are right - MySQL does not support CTEs or windowing functions.  I've updated my answer to include a MySQL example (w/ a SQLFiddle link)

Comment: @Yearger - Your last answer was absolutely brilliant and I'm trying to implement for an edge case where the player has either ranked in the top 5 or bottom 5. For example if my offset is 4, the current implementation will only display 4 below if I am ranked #1. I'd like it to display 9 below. Similarly if I was ranked #2, I'd like it to display 1 above and 8 below. Thoughts?